# How to inject/add a condition to a parent controller from outside in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-backpack

**TL;DR**

In my Laravel App, I have a list of controllers named A, B, C, etc (some of the are located in my vendor), which extend from a parent controller named P (located in the vendor) and use controller P's constructor. How can I add a condition Q (if-statement) to my P controller's constructor from outside.

---

**Long Story**

In my Laravel App (Backpack for Laravel), I have a list of controllers named PostCrudController, CategoryCrudController, CommentCrudController, etc (some of the are located in my vendor), which extend from a parent controller named CrudController (located in the vendor) and use CrudController's constructor.

***PostCrudController, CategoryCrudController, CommentCrudController, etc's structure:***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

class PostCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Post::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/post');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings(trans('general.post'), trans('general.posts'));
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

***CrudController's structure:***

```
<?php

namespace Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class CrudController extends Controller
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public $crud;
    public $data = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ($this->crud) {
            return;
        }

        // ---------------------------
        // Create the CrudPanel object
        // ---------------------------
        // Used by developers inside their ProductCrudControllers as
        // $this->crud or using the CRUD facade.
        //
        // It's done inside a middleware closure in order to have
        // the complete request inside the CrudPanel object.
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->crud = app()->make('crud');

            $this->crud->setRequest($request);

            $this->setupDefaults();
            $this->setup();
            $this->setupConfigurationForCurrentOperation();

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I want to add a condition Q (if-statement) to all my PostCrudController, CategoryCrudController, CommentCrudController, etc controllers. This is the discussed if-statement:

```
if (!backpack_user()->hasAnyPermission(['post.create']))
{
    $this->crud->denyAccess('create');
}
```

Is it possible to inject/add this condition Q to the parent controller (CrudController) constructor, rather than adding this condition to all the controllers's setup method? (I tested, and this condition works in both cases)

---

**What i've tried so far**

**I know that these solutions work:**

- I can simply add this Q condtion to my PostCrudController, CategoryCrudController, CommentCrudController, etc controller's setup method, or to the vendor's blade files.
- This Q condition has its functionality if I put that inside my CrudController's construct_ method
  But these solutions doesn't seem too be smart to me.

**What I've tried unsuccessfully so far to reach to a better solution:**

- Was defining a controller HasPermissionController, added the condition Q to its constructor, and bound it to the CrudController, in the AppServiceProvider. Which didn't work, as expected: because CrudController isn't requested directly.

  ***HasPermissionController's structure:***

  ```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    class HasPermissionController
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            if (!backpack_user()->hasAnyPermission(['post.create']))
            {
                $this->crud->denyAccess('create');
            }
        }
    }
  ```

  ***AppServiceProvider's structure:***

  ```
    <?php

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        public function register()
        {
            //
        }

        public function boot()
        {
            $this->app->bind(\Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController::class, \App\Http\Controllers\HasPermissionController::class);
        }
    }
  ```

Appreciate any suggestions?

P.S. I already defined a middleware for all my routes to check if the user has the authority to access the route. The job of this `$this->crud->denyAccess('create');` condition is to check for example if the user does have authority to the crud's list, but doesn't have authority to that crud's create, simply assigns a false access for the crud's create, which results in not showing the create button inside the list page (backpack uses this strategy inside its blade files to show or hide the buttons).

Comment: Didn't you post this as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73358176/how-to-inject-add-a-condition-to-a-parent-controller-from-outside-in-laravel before?  What happened to the attempt of adding a common parent controller?

Comment: @NicoHaase, yes, the question was closed and no one opened it, even after that I added all the details. So, I decided to delete that and post it again.

Comment: Then please take the time to add more details to this new question, instead of simply posting the exact same problem again

Comment: @NicoHaase, I did. What is missing now?

Comment: @NicoHaase, As I mentioned above, I tried to define a HasPermission Controller/Service and bound it to the CrudController in the AppServiceProvider, but it didn't work, because the CrudController (the parent controller) is not requested directly. Am I right?

Comment: @NicoHaase, is my binding implementation wrong? If I could find a way to bound a service/controller to my parrent controller, it might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood your question, but can you create an `App\CrudController` that extends `Backpack\CrudController`, and in `CategoryCrudController` you extend you `App\CrudController` and not  the package `Backpack\CrudController`.

You can then override the `setup()` in your `App\CrudController`.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already thought about that. But, first, as I mentioned in my question, "some of them are located in my vendor", (for cases in which I want to add the permission to my filemanager, etc.) and so, I cannot extend their controllers from my new controller, right? second, in this case I have to change parrent controller for all my controllers. I am looking for a trick; the short solution. I also wanted to suggest to backpack to fix this, but had zero time.

Comment: For the vendor ones you should create one in App, and then bind them in the Service Provider. Make sure you are correctly binding it, do a dd() or something to make sure your Controller is loaded and your binding is working.

Comment: I'm still looking for a better (with on place to be changed) solution. Until then, I pass this approach. But if I find no better solution, I'll get back to this solution. thanks again for your suggestions.